# Workflow 4 Service Application and InstanceContextMode & ConcurrencyMode

Tags: wcf, service, workflow-foundation-4, instancecontextmode

The question is pretty simple: how do you set InstanceContextMode & ConcurrencyMode in WF4 WCF Workflow Service Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, they have no effect of workflow services.